# how to make this UI to add friend

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

When we go to facebook and press status button, it presents a view where you can select friends, we can either press the circle to select friends 
or we can type friends` name in tableview header (it's called To:Friends), it will list the search result. I am trying to figure out how to make the UI on tableview Header (To:Friends). 
Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I was trying search bar, but couldn't make it like that.

Comment: that's too broad question sorry, but that's gonna be closed for sure. Make sure you read FAQ hwo to ask proper question

Comment: I was also thinking of textfield.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski hey, if you don't want to help me, that's fine. I am struggling here......

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try the following open source implementation.

[soofani-thcontactpicker](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/soofani-thcontactpicker)

Comment: Although this is potentially quite a good answer, it is essentially a "link only" answer. You should include some information from your links so that if the information behind the links is ever changed/lost, the answer still makes sense. See [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: thank you, that`s exactly what  I am looking for.

Comment: I'm glad to help you.